# Microshift AdventX drop bar lever spring position

Tags: brake-levers, microshift

My left brake lever spring was not pulling the lever back and I checked and it was bent. I removed the lever and fixed the spring, but I don't know how to put it back. I can't find any tutorials nor an image with the right position. Can anyone please help me with some info or an image with the lever and spring in the right position?

[image]
[image]

Thank you!